# Azure pipeline failing to pass date string to powershell script Unexpected token error

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have an Azure pipeline in place, I am trying to get it to pass a deployment name to a powershell script. The deployment name is formed, however it doesnt convert the date the way I want it, it is sending the deployment name as `app-name-$(Date:yyyyMMdd)`

The full YAML code can be found below.

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

parameters:
  - name: repoPrefix
    displayName: Repo Prefix
    type: string
    default: app-name
    values: 
      - app-name
  - name: env
    displayName: Environment
    type: string
    default: dev
    values: 
      - dev
      - prod

name: "${{ parameters.repoPrefix }}-${{ parameters.env }}-$(Date:yyyyMMdd)"

variables:
  - name: DeploymentName1
    value: $[counter(format('{0:yyyyMMdd}', pipeline.startTime), 1)]
  - name: DeploymentLabel
    value: "${{ parameters.repoPrefix }}-${{ parameters.env }}-$(Date:yyyyMMdd)"
    

stages:
  - stage:
    displayName: Deploy
    jobs:
      - deployment: Deploy
        displayName: "Run ${{ parameters.repoPrefix }} IaC deployment (${{ parameters.env }})"
        environment: ${{ parameters.env }}

        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - checkout: self
                  fetchDepth: 1


                - task: AzureCLI@2
                  displayName: 'Deployment'
                  inputs:
                    azureSubscription: 'service_connection'
                    scriptType: 'ps'
                    scriptLocation: 'scriptPath'
                    scriptPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Deploy_Iac.ps1'
                    arguments: "-location:'UKSouth' -deployment_name ${{variables.DeploymentName1}}"
```